# Returning min and max order dates per Client

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a a table of clients. I have another of their (many) orders. I want to return the client with a min(order_date) and max(order_date) ... e.g. the date of the first and last order. I've started with the following, but it's returning the date of the very first order in the table (rather than first order per client).

thanks in advance

```
SELECT dbo.job.job_no, 
   wo_begin_dt = ( SELECT MIN(dbo.work_order.wo_begin_dt) 
    FROM dbo.job LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.work_order 
    ON dbo.job.job_no = dbo.work_order.job_no)
FROM        dbo.job                  
ORDER BY    dbo.job.job_no
```

Comment: How is a job linked to a client? And do you want the min/max times per job, or per client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your table structure, you need something like:

```
SELECT ClientField, MIN(OrderDate), MAX(OrderDate)
FROM ClientTable C
INNER JOIN OrderTable O
    ON O.ClientID = C.ClientID
GROUP BY ClientField
```